# Access denied - while calling wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, access-denied

I have a wcf service and I am calling it from another website.

The service is doing some decoding job.

The problem happening is :

For a few vehicle, the data is decoded very well, but for a few vehicle is is showing error.

**Error code : 500
Error Message : Failed Authentication + Access denied**

I have added a screen shot of the error.

NOTE : For some vehicle it is working fine.
[image]

AS it is working for a few vehicle, I dont think it is an issue with code of decoding.

Please suggest what could be the issue here..

Code to access the service is :

```
function ResetValues(infoType)
{
    var $jDecode = jQuery.noConflict();
    var decoderUrl = $jDecode("input[id*=hdnVINDecoderURL]").val();
    var vin = $jDecode("input[id*=txtVIN]").val().toUpperCase();
    var styleId = null;
    var trim = $jDecode("#lbTrimRecords").val();

    if(trim != null)
    {
        styleId = trim.substring(trim.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, trim.lastIndexOf(")"));
    }

    //Declaring parameter to be passed to the called function.
    var paramList = '{"vin":"'+vin+'","styleID":"'+styleId+'","infoType":"'+infoType+'"}';

    //To show the loading image
    document.getElementById('imgLoading').style.visibility = 'visible';

    try
    {
        $jDecode.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: decoderUrl + 'GetFactoryInformation/' + vin + '/' + styleId + '/' + infoType,
            //data: paramList,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                dataObject = data;
```

Comment: You have to show the code. Specifically how you are accessing the service **in the code**.

Comment: @Yuck -- Please see the edit..let me know if I need to give some more information.

Comment: Have you tried to URL-encode the parameters : vin, styleId, etc. ?

Comment: No.. But what I am not able to understand is..the same code and everything is working fine for a few values..where as showing error for a few..

Comment: Can you list a few that work and which one fails?

Comment: Try to figure out whether there's anything in common with the failing values - maybe they all contain a certain character?

Comment: Well they are random VINs, for some it is working and for some it is not..They are consistent..They were working fine before, that means all of them are having data..This issue came all of a sudden now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was a null value was coming and it was throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted calls a web service which in turn calls a web service via WCF.

The error that you are getting is 500, which is a http error which means internal error.

The error is probably related to the amount of data, WCF has a max request size which can be configured. If the amount of data returned from the web service exceeds the max allowed, you will get an internal error on the web site.

To test it use the wcf test client directly against the WCF service. Compare the amount of data returned.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..I did test it with the wcftest client..and it worked very well for all the VINs supplied.